# Dereferencing and increment with ostream_iterator

Tags: c++

I found this code from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::ostream_iterator<int> i1(std::cout, ", ");
    std::fill_n(i1, 5, -1);
    std::ostream_iterator<double> i2(std::cout);
    *i2++ = 3.14;
}
```

Why do you need the `++` in `*i2++ = 3.14;`?

Comment: You don't need it. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: The example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator%3D) says it's optional. It has some examples that use it and some that don't.

Comment: See also the documentation for the `OutputIterator`  (of which `ostream_iterator` is an implementation). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, when writing to a range, you'd want to move to the next element after writing to one. For most iterators, like e.g. a `std::vector::iterator`, that has to be done explicitly. So it kind of makes sense to include it, if only for consistency.

In the particular case of `std::ostream_iterator`, it does not have an actual effect though, and could be left out. You cannot overwrite an "element" of the output range anyways, advancing is implicit (and only implicit, i.e. both the increment operators as well as derefencing are no-ops in this context).

The important part is only the [`operator =`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator%3D), as explained in the relevant documentation:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <iterator>
>
> int main()
> {
>     std::ostream_iterator<int> i1(std::cout, ", ");
>     *i1++ = 1; // usual form, used by standard algorithms
>     *++i1 = 2;
>     i1 = 3; // neither * nor ++ are necessary
>     std::ostream_iterator<double> i2(std::cout);
>     i2 = 3.14;
> }
> ```

Comment: Note: The output iterator expects a call to `operator++` between each write using `operator*`. So using the `*i2++` seems like a natural way of doing it. [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) => `Assignment through an output iterator is expected to alternate with incrementing.`

Comment: @LokiAstari That's what I was trying to explain in the first paragraph; I hope it was clear. Conceptually, the increment is important and makes sense, but in this special case, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator has no effect on `std::ostream_iterator`. Assigning to `*i2` automatically advances the output stream.

It's provided so that `ostream_iterator` can be used anywhere that an ordinary iterator is allowed, and most iterators have to be incremented explicitly.

Even with an ordinary iterator, it's generally only necessary to increment it if you use it multiple times. In the code snippet you found, where it's used just once, incrementing is totally unnecessary. It would be more reasonable if it were inside a loop.